# how to detect if the iframe is fully loaded in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Is there anyway that I can detect if the iframe is completed loading?
This is my iframe code:

```
<div ng-if="isLoadDone" class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw margin-bottom"></span></div>
  </div>
<iframe ng-if="isLoadDone" class="app-iframe" ng-src="{{trustedApplUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Basically I want to display the spinner if the iframe is not full loaded.
I want to detect if iframe is completed loading not start loading. I was able to find the way to find out if the iframe starts loading but not when the iframe is completed loading. Any idea?
Thanks
-Kim

Comment: I do recommend listening to the `load` event. But seriously, did you use google before asking?!

Comment: yes, I did using google before asking but I have seen the load event only

Comment: Right, there may not be a way just using angular.

Comment: "load" event is for detecting when the iframe is loading not when the iframe is finished loading. Any suggestion how to find when the iframe is completed loading?

Comment: @Kim have you solve this problem?

Answer (score 18):

```
<iframe (load)="myLoadEvent()" id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

In component

```
myLoadEvent(){
// do your task
}
```

This works in angular6.
This is not to identify if iframe is fully loaded. But will help anyone who lands here for iframe load

Comment: even though the question says Angular in the title, the tags and the code is all AngularJs.  **These are not the same framework**, so while this code would probably work in Angular 6, it's of little use to this question that targets AngularJs 1.x.

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple other ways to make it work with IE11 and Angular 4.

1. Using Renderer2

   `<iframe #iframe id="iframe" name="pdfPreview" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
   this._rndr.listen(this.iframeRef.nativeElement, 'load', (e) => { alert("works"); }`
2. Adding callback to window

   `<iframe onload="loadEvent(event)" id="iframe" name="pdfPreview" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
   (window as any).loadEvent = (event) => alert("works too");`

Comment: Method 1 worked just fine for an object element with an embeded pdf. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-onload](https://github.com/mikaturunen/ng-onload) for such things.

```
<iframe ng-onload="myLoadEvent()" class="app-iframe" ng-src="{{trustedApplUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: ng-onload is detected when the iframe loading is started not when the iframe is finished loading